# Exclude Post post type from Search

Tags: wordpress, post

I have several custom post types in my blog. How can I exclude the Post post type from Search so only my custom post types will be displayed?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer after some digging. Simply add the following hidden field in your search form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="custom1" />
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="custom2" />
```

This restricts search only to the post types `custom1` and `custom2`.